black screen after booting and i cant see login screen
Ubuntu version: fossa 20.04
I encountered a problem when booting Ubuntu. After seeing the line "/dev/nvme0n1p1 clean files, blocks", the screen goes blank and stays black. There's no error message or any indication of what's happening—just a blank screen. Normally, I would see a loading screen followed by the login screen after this line. However, in this case, nothing happens, I haven't installed any new programs since the last time it was working. I am able to boot into Windows without any issues.
enter image description here
Thank you in advance for your help!

What version of Ubuntu? Any recent changes, updates added new programs since last time it was working? Please use edit and update the question.

I discovered that I can boot into Ubuntu when I add nomodeset quiet splash to the boot parameters, but I have no idea why this works.
